# Setting up Windows XP with bootcamp - Why does OSX Boot and Skip XP Installation?

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, boot-camp

I am attempting to install Windows XP on my Macbook. I use bootcamp assistant and partion 32GB for windows. I insert the XP disk and I go through the initial blue screen disk formatting screens. After the partion is formatted (side question: which option is correct to choose: NTFS or FAT?) and the files are copied, it claims it will shutdown and continue installation after restarting. The computer boots up the normal way with OSX Leopard. What am I missing? The only choices I'm really given are for partition size and File System. Is there a way to continue setup using a hotkey as it boots? I figured that having the CD in the drive would be what would tell the computer to continue setup. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot off the hard-drive not the CD at that point.  Bootcamp should set the XP partition as the default during the install, but I guess for some reason it has not, so just hold down the "option" key during the gray apple reboot screen, and you will be prompted after a while with the partition to boot from (OSX or WinXP).

[image: Boot Selection]

Select the XP one and you should be back on track.

I would recommend that you use NTFS for the partition, it is a more robust file system than FAT32.